# Parse/extract table data using python

Tags: python, html

```
<html> 
<table border="1px"> 
<tr>
<td>yes</td>
<td>no</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Is there any way to get the contents of the table (yes ,no) besides beautifulsoup??

A python beginner,any help or any kind of direction will be of great help.

Thank you

Comment: Yes there is. Should you do it without a parser? Probably not.

Comment: okay,how do i parse it ??.. any tutorial sites that you might suggest??... googling it dint give fruitful result..

Comment: If the structure of your markup is relatively stable and you can guarantee it's well-formatted, you can try using regexes. (For example, one for enumerating table rows, the other for getting cells within a row).

Comment: @PHP: the reason people like BeautifulSoup is that it is very flexible in the HTML it accepts, which is useful since a lot of what you find on the internet is broken. Things like `lxml` and `HTMLParser` are rather stricter on what mistakes they allow.

Comment: @Xion : Will check out regexes. @katrielalex ,have been using beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `HTMLParser` module that comes with the Python standard library.

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> data = '''
... <html> 
... <table border="1px"> 
... <tr>
... <td>yes</td>
... <td>no</td>
... </tr>
... </table>
... </html>
... '''
>>> class TableParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self):
...         HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
...         self.in_td = False
...     
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         if tag == 'td':
...             self.in_td = True
...     
...     def handle_data(self, data):
...         if self.in_td:
...             print data
...     
...     def handle_endtag(self, tag):
...         self.in_td = False
... 
>>> p = TableParser()
>>> p.feed(data)
yes
no
```