# New items added to list from HTML Table using HTMLParser in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, html-table, html-parsing

With the help of documentation about [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)  and this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690452/8198803) i tried to extract the data from the table, while extracting the data from the table between `<td>..</td>`, and appending to the list it `appends` new items when it has new `starttag` in it.

A small example explaining my problem below:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.in_td = False
        self._out = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.in_td = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.in_td = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_td:
            #print(data)
            self._out.append(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    link_raw = """
<html><p><center><h1>  Clash Report 1  </h1></center></p><p><table border=on>  <th> Errors </th><th>  Elements </th>
<tr>  <td>  Delete one of those.  </td>
<td>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549036  <br>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549042</td></tr>
<tr>  <td>  Delete one of those.  </td>
<td>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549036  <br>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549081</td></tr>
"""
    #<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><tr><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr></body></html>

    parser.feed(link_raw)
    print (parser._out)
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
['  Delete one of those.  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549036  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549042', '  Delete one of those.  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549036  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549081']
```

How to ignore those tags like `<Room Separation>` and `<br>` and append only the data in between the `<td>..</td>` to one item like this

> **Desired OUTPUT** 
>   ['  Delete one of those.  ', '  060 :   : Model Lines : id 549036  ', '  060 :  : Model Lines : id 549042', '  Delete
>   one of those.  ', '  060 :  : Model Lines : id 549036  ', '  060 :  :
>   Model Lines : id 549081']

Comment: HTMLParser is quite an old-fashioned way of parsing HTML. Are you sure you want to do it this way?

Comment: I actually don't want to but I can't figure out any way to use beautiful soup or other modules in IronPython!

Comment: Well that explains that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You seem to have succeeded.

Comment: Well I seem to have but not completely. The Ouput list has 10 items in it because of the tags like <Room Separation> and <br> between the table data<td> . On the other hand the Desired Output has only 6 items, which is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way of doing it is to keep a stack of tags, ignoring those that are in the way. Incidentally, since 'Room Separation' is not a kosher tag identifier, HTMLParser turns it into just plain 'room'.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self._stack = []
        self._out = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in ['br', 'room']: return
        self._stack.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self._stack.pop()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self._stack and self._stack[-1] == 'td':
            self._out.append(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    link_raw = """
<html><p><center><h1>  Clash Report 1  </h1></center></p><p><table border=on>  <th> Errors </th><th>  Elements </th>
<tr>  <td>  Delete one of those.  </td>
<td>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549036  <br>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549042</td></tr>
<tr>  <td>  Delete one of those.  </td>
<td>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549036  <br>  060 : <Room Separation> : Model Lines : id 549081</td></tr>
"""
    #<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><tr><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr></body></html>

    parser.feed(link_raw)
    result = parser._out
    print (len(result))
    print (result)
```

Output:

```
10
['  Delete one of those.  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549036  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549042', '  Delete one of those.  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549036  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549081']
```

Comment: I got the same output, I am expecting the **Desired OUTPUT** please look in my question. I really cant understand  in your code why does the `parser._stack` contains this in the list `['html', 'p', 'table']` it doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: First, the output from my code is easily transformed into the output that you want. Consider one instance. You want `[' Delete one of those. ', ' 060 : : Model Lines : id 549036 ',` I gave you `['  Delete one of those.  ', '  060 : ', ' : Model Lines : id 549036  ',` Smply join pairs of strings in the series. Second, the tags you mention such as `html` are parsed out of the HTML by HTMLParser. My code simply places them on the stack as it finds them and then pops them off when it finds their corresponding closing tags. This is how it knows when it's 'inside' a `td` cell, and must collect char.

Comment: You can check that first assertion of mine by opening an editor an placing my result in a line directly under what you want. That's what I just did.

Comment: I checked as you said comparing the two can't really find any difference. Its the same letter to letter

Comment: I meant compare what you wanted with what my script produced.

Comment: It really doesn't help for me, if have to join the subsequent items i would have done it using the code which i had. Thanks a lot for your effort to look at my post and replying back but this is going nowhere. I am finding other alternatives for Iron python to parse HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152198/discussion-between-raja-and-bill-bell).